# Asking user to input two numbers, store them in memory, doing addition and substraction and display both result

Tags: mips

I'm new to MIPS, and I'm working on this question, my code wold assemble, but after I hit the run buttom and entered the first number, it would show a runtime exception: Runtime exception at 0x00400018: address out of range 0x00000000

I don't understand what's happening to my code, can anyone help me?

```
    .data
str1:   .asciiz "Enter number 1: " 

str2:   .asciiz "Enter number 2: " 

str3:   .asciiz "The sum of the two number is: "

str4:   .asciiz "The difference of the two number is: "

num1:   .word 4

num2:   .word 4

    .text
    .globl main
main:

la  $t0, str1

li  $v0, 4      #syscall code for print_str

la  $a0, ($t0)  #address of string to print

syscall         #print str1

la  $s0, num1

li  $v0, 5      #syscall code for read int 

syscall         #read int

sw  $s0, ($v0)  #store the enterd value in num1

    la  $t1, str2
    li  $v0, 4      #syscall for print_str
    la  $a0, ($t1)      #address of string to print
    syscall         #print str2
    la  $s1, num2
    li  $v0, 5      #syscall code for read int
    syscall         #read int
    sw  $s1, ($v0)  #store the entered value in num2

    add $s2, $s0, $s1   #add num1 and num2

    la  $t2, str3
    li  $v0, 4      #syscall for print_str
    la  $a0, ($t2)      #address of str3
    la  $a1, ($s2)      #address of the sum
    syscall         #print str3 and the sum

    sub $s3, $s0, $s1   #substract num1 and num2    ERROR COULD BE HERE

    la  $t3, str4
    li  $v0, 4      #syscall for print_str
    la  $a0, ($t3)      #address of str4
    la  $a1, ($s3)      #address of the difference
    syscall         #print str4 and the difference
    li  $v0, 10     #exit
    syscall
```

Error in C:\Users\Desktop\exercise2.s line 18: Runtime exception at 0x00400018: address out of range 0x00000000

Go: execution terminated with errors.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the error you describe. However, `sw  $s0, ($v0)` is incorrect since your address is in `$s0` and your value is in `$v0`, not the other way around. You need to read the error messages from the simulator carefully and think about how they correspond to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Many problems in your code.

`la  $a0, ($t0)` is incorrect. The assembler should warn you. `la` is a two instructions macro  that` loads an address from a label, while $t0 is a register (that already holds the value of str1).

It should be replaced by `la $a0, str1` or (much better because it is a   a unique instruction) `mov $a0, $t1` as you already did this computation for $t1. You have the same problem for str2, str3 and str4. 
But there is no need to use a temporary register and you could directly do the computation in $a0.

There is another problem. According to [documentation](https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html) after `syscall` 5 "$v0 contains integer read". So the `sw  $s0, ($v0)` after reading the ints are incorrect. What should be stored is `$v0` and the store address is num1 and has already been loaded in $s0.

`add $s2, $s1, $s0` is also incorrect, as $s0 and $s1 values are integer addresses, not integer values.

Last, you cannot print at once a string and an integer. It must be done in two syscalls : syscall 4 to print a string and syscall 1 to print the integer.

```
   .data
str1:   .asciiz "Enter number 1: " 
str2:   .asciiz "Enter number 2: " 
str3:   .asciiz "The sum of the two number is: "
str4:   .asciiz "The difference of the two number is: "
num1:   .word 4
num2:   .word 4

    .text
    .globl main
main:
    la  $a0, str1
    li  $v0, 4      #syscall code for print_str
    syscall         #print str1

    li  $v0, 5      #syscall code for read int
    syscall         #read int
    mov $s0, $v0    ## keep the value of int in a register
    la  $t1, num2
    sw  $v0, ($t1)  #store the entered value in num2


    li  $v0, 4      #syscall for print_str
    la  $a0, str2      #address of string to print
    syscall         #print str2

    li  $v0, 5      #syscall code for read int
    syscall         #read int
    mov $s1, $v0    ## keep the value of int in a register
    la  $t1, num2
    sw  $v0, ($t1)  #store the entered value in num2

    add $s2, $s0, $s1   #add num1 and num2

    la  $a0, str3
    li  $v0, 4      #syscall for print_str
    syscall         #print str3
    li  $v0, 1      #syscall for print integer
    mov $a0, $s2    #value of the sum
    syscall         #print sum

    sub $s3, $t0, $t1   #substract num1 and num2

    la  $a0, str4
    li  $v0, 4      #syscall for print_str
    syscall         #print str4
    li  $v0, 1      #syscall for print integer
    mov $a0, $s3    #value of the diff
    syscall         #print diff value
```

BTW, storing the integers is useless. I kept them because it is in the title of the question, but it you just need the sum and diff, the `sw` instructions and corresponding `la` can be suppressed.

Comment: Thank you,  that is soooooo helpful